# Django rest framework DateField format

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have drf model which is containe DateField. That field default format is "YYYY-MM-DD" just i want to convert "DD-MM-YYYY" how can is possible.

*models.py*

```
class Reminder(BaseModel):
    content = models.TextField()
    schedule_date = models.DateField()
    schedule_time = models.TimeField()
    is_release = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class ReminderSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    schedule_date = serializers.DateField(format="%d-%m-%Y")
    class Meta:
        model = Reminder
        fields = ('id','content','created_at','schedule_date','schedule_time','user_id','is_release','is_deleted',)
```

in serializer.py i just give the format but that format convering only in List page. as you can see listing is okey but the POST action field is not converted. [API please look at image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKpYS.png)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can take a look at [DRF's docs on this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datefield). Basically `format` only deals with output, but for input you need to include `input_formats` - for your case you can do `schedule_date = serializers.DateField(format="%d-%m-%Y", input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y', 'iso-8601'])`

It's up to you whether you want to keep the iso-8601 there.